# Transcoded MPEG-4 video not playing on Android's native app

Tags: android, ios, android-mediaplayer, codec

I'm doing some transcoding programmatically and created [an mpeg4 video](http://ppl.ug/LTFJExFuE3g/). The problem is that it does NOT play on Android's native player (Galaxy Nexus and Nexus S). See error and codec details below.

I have files that play successfully and files that fail to play. What exactly is wrong with this file that Android is unable to create the media player?

**Question: Why isn't the file being played?**

More info: the transcode was created using an iPhone. Pseudocode: `AVAssetExportSession->>exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler(AVFileTypeMPEG4)`

Here's the codec of the video:
[image: Video codec details]

Here's the error:

```
02-14 12:39:33.243: E/MediaPlayerService(132):   error: -2147483648
02-14 12:39:33.243: E/MediaPlayer(25598): Unable to to create media player
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598): Unable to open content: file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/IMG_0002.MOV-st.mp4
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:976)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:955)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:918)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:870)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:238)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:52)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:492)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.view.SurfaceView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.java:249)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at com.android.gallery3d.app.MoviePlayer$4.run(MoviePlayer.java:147)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 12:39:33.251: W/VideoView(25598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 12:39:33.251: D/VideoView(25598): Error: 1,0
```

Comment: can you please share link for transcoding programmatically... Or any link to blog if you have written on this topic. It will be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: I corrected the video link. Here it is as well: http://ppl.ug/LTFJExFuE3g/ - there's a download button at the top of the page.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I actually did get this to work a bit after I posted this.  I'll try to get my answer posted later today for everyone.

Comment: @Chris - that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running into the same problem, I did a lot of digging around and tried many different techniques to solve this issue.  Many other SO questions of the same type have gotten responses of "just save the .MOV file that the iPhone creates as an .mp4".  In theory this would work since they are both containers, however, this (at least for me) lead to the same "unable to open content" error as mentioned here (and on every device I tested with).  The solution for me did end up being using AVAssetExportSession.  This is the code I used:

```
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:self.sharingMovieUrl options:nil];
NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];
if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality]) {
     AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];    
    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp3.mp4"];    
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];    
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{        
        switch ([exportSession status]) {

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                //If this fails, it might be because the temorary
                //files weren't cleaned and this isn't overwriting
                //the temporary filename
                NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                //Perform any failed logic                
                break;                
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:                
                NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                //Perform any cancel logic                
                break;                
            default:
                //This should have been a success                                
                //File should be saved at filePath
                //Upload file from here
                break;                
        }        
    }];
}
```

Comment: I should add that I've only been able to test this from an iPhone 4S as of now.